# Need an expert in T-Sql SQL to solve the averages per week day issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have decided to write a post because I run out of idea how can modify the query I wrote to pull the average number of shipments and pieces per day. 
The query basically picks all the shipment and pieces from OrderTbl and count them based on the office and delivery date. 
It works all right until it comes to Saturday and Sundays when often there are no orders to deliver. I found that then those days without deliveries stays uncountable and the result is wrong.
For example, in February we got 4 Saturdays and 4 Sundays but I am getting the result divided by 3 because as I mentioned before there was no deliveries over the weekend.

Please have a look on the query and let me know what sort of solution I should be looking solve this average count issue.

```
select [DAY],
    AVG(CAST(qty.PieceAmount as float)) as [PieceAmountAvg],
    AVG(CAST(qty.ShipmentAmount as float)) as [ShipmentAmountAVG]
from (
    select w = DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, OrderTbl.DelDate),
        [Day] = DATENAME(Weekday, OrderTbl.DelDate, ShipmentAmount = COUNT(distinct OrderTbl.CEXP), PieceAmount = SUM(OrderTbl.Pieces) from dbo.OrderTbl(nolock)
            where OrderTbl.Cbur = 'GBLR'
            and (
                OrderTbl.DelDate >= '20170201'
                and OrderTbl.DelDate <= '20170228'
                ) group by DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, OrderTbl.DelDate), DATENAME(WEEKDAY, OrderTbl.DelDate), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, OrderTbl.DelDate)) as qty
    group by [Day]
    order by case when Day = 'Monday' then 1 when Day = 'Tuesday' then 2 when Day = 'Wednesday' then 3 when Day = 'Thursday' then 4 when Day = 'Friday' then 5 when Day = 'Saturday' then 6 when Day = 'Sunday' then 7 end asc;
    )
```

I will appreciate much your your  help.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: @jarlh . . . Well, right justified would be worse ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I hope I'll never see that...

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you really should stop using nolock unless you are ok with your queries being mostly correct most of the time. That hint can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Probably the best option for dealing with this would be to create and use a calendar table so you can control not just weekends but holidays and all sorts of other one off situations.

Answer (score 1):

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table with this:

```
/* dates table */
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];
create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

Without taking the actual step of creating a table, you can use it inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with just this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
   order by [Date]
)
select [Date]
from dates;
```

And use either like so:

```
set datefirst 1;
select
    [day]
  , [PieceAmountAvg] = avg(cast(qty.PieceAmount as float))
  , [ShipmentAmountavg] = avg(cast(qty.ShipmentAmount as float))
from (
   select
         w             = datediff(week, 0, d.Date)
      , [Day]          = datename(Weekday, d.Date)
      , ShipmentAmount = count(distinct o.Cexp)
      , PieceAmount    = sum(o.Pieces)
      , DayOfWeek      = datepart(weekday, d.Date)
    from dates d
      left join dbo.OrderTbl o
        on d.date = o.DelDate
          and o.Cbur = 'gblr'
     --left join fexp (nolock) on fexp.Cexp = fexpsui.Cexp
     where (d.Date >= '20170201' and d.Date <= '20170228')
     group by
       datediff(week, 0, d.Date)
     , datename(weekday, d.Date)
     , datepart(weekday, d.Date)
   ) as qty
 group by [Day], DayOfWeek
 order by DayOfWeek
  /*case
    when Day = 'Monday' then 1
    when Day = 'Tuesday' then 2
    when Day = 'Wednesday' then 3
    when Day = 'Thursday' then 4
    when Day = 'Friday' then 5
    when Day = 'Saturday' then 6
    when Day = 'Sunday' then 7 
    end asc
    */
```

If you `set datefirst 1` you could `order by datepart(weekday, d.Date)` instead of your `case` expression.

If you wanted to create a full Calendar table, you would also be able to avoid all of those `datepart()` and `datename()` functions.

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-sql/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in sql Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [tsql Function to Determine Holidays in sql Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_table_date - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=61519)

Comment: Hey SqlZim, I was fell sceptically when I first looked at the examples you have posted but then when I sat down second time I actually see logic behind. I think that by creating common table expression I should manage to solve it but I need some time to get this done properly. Many thanks SqlZim

Comment: Hi SqlZim, I did accept your answer but found that I cannot reference dates  from Date table properly for some reason. On line 22 ,DayOfWeek = datepart(weekday, d.Date I am getting "The multi-part identifier "d.Date" could not be bound.". I tried to modify it but in vain.

Comment: @piotr My apologies, I misplaced it in the wrong part of the query. Corrected now

Comment: Thanks SQLZim, I have one more issue that is the avg of shipment is working fine but for some reason I am not getting correct number of pieces per day instead it pick all number of shipments. Do you have a clue how to mend it?

Comment: @piotr It's hard to guess what's going on. Do you have some sample tables and data I could test against?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dummy Date table with every date possible that you'll need. 
Then RIGHT JOIN to this table in your inner query.
That way you'll have a record for every day even if no orders occurred.